# How to tell restkit which entity mapping to use

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit-0.20

I have an iOS app that is using Restkit to pull info from a server.  I have reached a point where I am using more than one CoreData Entity.  I have set up an new entity mapping for restkit but my response from the server results in no mappable values because it is using the wrong entity mapping.  Can someone clue me in on how to tell it which one to use.

Here are the two mappers:

```
RKEntityMapping *articleEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Gist" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id.text":             @"gistID",
 @"title.text":          @"title",
 @"hashtags.text":       @"hashtags",
 @"imageUrl.text":       @"imageUrl",
 @"description.text":    @"summary",
 @"copy.text":           @"fullArticle",
 @"articleId.text":      @"articleId"}];
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"gistID" ];

RKEntityMapping *userEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"UserInfo" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[userEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"firstName.text":      @"firstName",
 @"lastName.text":       @"lastName",
 @"birthDay.text":       @"birthDay",
 @"birthMonth.text":     @"birthMonth",
 @"birthYear.text":      @"birthYear"}];
userEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"birthDay" ];
```

I thought the `identificationAttributes` gave it the cue but it didn't seem to work.  There is no relationship between these two entities.  They come from completely unrelated API's on the server side.

Here is what I am using to make the request that uses `articleEntityMapping`

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil path:@"/rest/search?ip=255.255.255.0" parameters:search success:nil failure:nil];
```

Here is what I am using to make the request that `userEntityMapping` should use but doesn't.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil path:@"/rest/person/login?ip=255.255.255.0" parameters:postBody success:nil failure:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mappings are only half the story, the other half is the response descriptors. While the mappings tell RestKit how to convert the received data, the response descriptors tell RestKit when the mapping is appropriate to use. This is done by a combination of the path pattern and the key path parameters. The path pattern matches agains the URL used to get the data so you need to set that.

Comment: Wow thats embarrassing.  I have 3 response descriptors and failed to see the completely obvious `responseDescriptorWithMapping:`.  Thanks for the pointer Wain. (Again!)